# I need some help in my Java Assignment which is a simple program for managing phonecall

Tags: java, abstract-class

A1. Create an abstract class named PhoneCall that includes a String field for a phone number and a double field for the price of the call.

A2. Also, include a constructor that requires a phone number parameter and that sets the price to 0.0. Include a set method for the price. Also include three abstracts get methods—one that returns the phone number, another that returns the price of the call, and a third that displays information about the call.

A3.     Create two child classes of PhoneCall: IncomingPhoneCall and OutgoingPhoneCall.

- The IncomingPhoneCall constructor passes its phone number parameter to its parent’s constructor and sets the price of the call to 0.02. The method that displays the phone call information displays the phone number, the rate, and the price of the call (which is the same as the rate).

-----The OutgoingPhoneCall class includes an additional field that holds the time of the call in minutes. The constructor requires both a phone number and the time. The price is 0.04 per minute, and the display method shows the details of the call, including the phone number, the rate per minute, the number of minutes, and the total price.

---Write an application that demonstrates you can instantiate and display both IncomingPhoneCall and OutgoingPhoneCall objects. Save the files as PhoneCall.java, IncomingPhoneCall.java, OutgoingPhoneCall.java, and DemoPhoneCalls.java.

I have done only that below:

```
public abstract class PhoneCall
{

    private String phoneno;
    private double price;

    public PhoneCall(String phoneno, double price)
    {
        this.phoneno =  phoneno;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getphoneno()
    {
        return phoneno;
    }
    public double getprice()
    {
        return price = 0.0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
public class IncomingPhoneCall extends PhoneCall
{

    public IncomingPhoneCall(String phoneno, double price) {
        super(phoneno, price);

    }

}
public class OutgoingPhoneCall extends PhoneCall
{

    public OutgoingPhoneCall(String phoneno, double price) {
        super(phoneno, price);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a „can I haz codes?“-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** or visit **[the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks luk, I have updated my Q now with my existing work.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class PhoneCall
{

    String phoneNumber;
    double price;

     PhoneCall(String phoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber =  phoneNumber;
        this.price = 0.0;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public abstract void setPrice();

}
class IncomingPhoneCall extends PhoneCall {

    final static double RATE=0.02;
     IncomingPhoneCall(String phoneNumber){
        super(phoneNumber);
        setPrice();
    }
    public void setPrice() {
        price = 0.02;
    }
     void info(){
        System.out.println("Incoming phone call"+getPhoneNumber()+
                " "+RATE+" per call.Total is $"+getPrice());
    }
      public String getPhoneNumber()
      {
          return phoneNumber;
      }
      public double getPrice()
      {
          return price;
      }

}
class OutgoingPhoneCall extends PhoneCall {

    final static double RATE = 0.04;
    private int minutes;
     OutgoingPhoneCall(String phoneNumber, int minutes){
        super(phoneNumber);
        this.minutes = minutes;
        setPrice();;
    }
    public void setPrice() {
        price = 0.04;
    }
    void info() {
        System.out.println("Outgoing phone call " + getPhoneNumber() + " "
                + RATE + " per minute at " + minutes + " minutes. Total is $" + price*minutes);
    }
     public String getPhoneNumber()
     {
         return phoneNumber;
     }
     public double getPrice()
     {
         return price;
     }

}


public class DemoPhoneCalls {
public static void main(String [] args) {

    IncomingPhoneCall incomingPhoneCall=new IncomingPhoneCall("310-332-0908");
    OutgoingPhoneCall outgoingPhoneCall=new OutgoingPhoneCall("310-000-0102",20);

    incomingPhoneCall.info();
    outgoingPhoneCall.info();
 }
}
```